# JavaScript Can't create multiple inputs

Tags: javascript, forms

OK I am very new to JS and people have been great helping  me out but I am having an issue creating a form with multiple input elements. The second element is appearing but the first element is populating with the input.value from the second element and I get no value in the second

I've not used the DOM functions before so I may be messing up how I am calling them. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
newWindow = window.open("", null, "height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");  


newWindow.document.title = "Info Window";


// create a form and set properties
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.action = 'http://google.com';
form.method = 'post';

// insert into the body of the new window
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(form);

// add text before the input
var cNumLab = document.createElement('cNumLab');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Craft Number:'));

// add a text input
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.name = 'input';
input.value = 'Enter Craft Number Here';
form.appendChild(input);

//add linebreak
var linebreak = document.createElement('br');
form.appendChild(linebreak);

// add text before the input
var sDescL = document.createElement('sDescL');
form.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Short Desc:'));

// add a text input
var sDesc = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'text';
input.name = 'sDesc';
input.value = 'Enter Short Description Here:';
form.appendChild(sDesc);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your second "input" the variable references the first field "input" and not the later "sDesc"

Should be

```
// add a text input
var sDesc = document.createElement('input');
sDesc.type = 'text';
sDesc.name = 'sDesc';
sDesc.value = 'Enter Short Description Here:';
form.appendChild(sDesc);
```